# Why was GeoFire's function getLocationForKey overleaped?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, location, geofire

I try to get a user's location with a function called getLocationForKey (Geofire). The Location is stored in Firebase. I call this function in func tableview:

```
// Get user Distance
    var myLocation = CLLocation()
    myLocation = getUserLocation(ref.authData.uid)
    print("myLocation: [\(myLocation.coordinate.latitude), \(myLocation.coordinate.longitude)]")
```

getUserLocation looks as follows:

```
func getUserLocation(userID: String) -> CLLocation {

    var userLocation = CLLocation()
    print(userID)

    let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: ref.childByAppendingPath("locations"))
    geoFire.getLocationForKey(userID, withCallback: { (location, error) in

        if (location != nil)
        {
            userLocation = CLLocation(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
            print("userLocation:  [\(userLocation.coordinate.latitude), \(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)]")
        }
        else if (error != nil)
        {
            print("An error occurred getting the location for \(userID): \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        else
        {
            print("GeoFire does not contain a location for \(userID)")
        }
    })

    return userLocation
}
```

As a result, i get this:

myLocation: [0.0, 0.0]

userLocation:  [123.456, 123.456]

which seems strange to me, because somehow the code in getLocationForKey was jumped over, i get myLocation first and afterwards userLocation. Does anyone know why? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is that the getLocationForKey is not being jumped over - it is executing as shown by print("userLocation... printing the location.

However, the print("myLocation... statement (outside the block) is occurring before the code in getLocationForKey has time to return the Firebase data.

Remember that Firebase is asynchronous so you need to process the data *after* Firebase returns that data, usually inside the block.

Comment: Thanks. Considering the asynchronous networking, it's probably not a good idea to call getUserLocation in the tableview function where I allocate data to the cells. Otherwise I would get "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" Do you maybe know where/in which function I should try retrieving the user location?

Comment: @yoshimoshi Is this a list of users that's presented in a tableView with something like their name and location?

Comment: Yes that's right, but i solved this problem by loading all the necessary information before i even load this viewcontroller. Is this the common way to do it?

Comment: @yoshimoshi It's very situational. You should definitely load the datasource array before refreshing the tableView - an in this case, it may be appropriate to load it before displaying the viewController. In general, you would query for/observe the data you want, retrieve it in a snapshot and move the data to an array, which is the dataSource of your table view. However, if there's a million items, then a different strategy would be used as you would only need to display a small section of the data in the tableView at a time.